# Can a set map to a larger set

Tags: complex-analysis

> Given $f(z)=z^5$, $z\in \mathbb{C}$, what is the image under $f$ of the piece of pie of the disk of radius $2$, cut out by the positive $x$-axis and the radial line at angle $\pi/4$?

The image is the piece of pie of the disk of radius $32$, cut by the $x$-axis and the radial line at angle $5\pi/4$. Clearly, the output image contains more numbers than the input image. That means the numbers in the input image are mapping to more than one number in the output image. But how is it possible in a function? Am I misinterpreting something?

[image: Here's a sketch of the situation.]

Comment: Consider the map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which sends $x$ to $2x$. The image of the interval $[0,1]$ is $[0,2]$, which is twice as big. The point is that while $[0,1]$ and $[0,2]$ have different sizes in the sense of measure, they have the same cardinality. So there is no issue in having such a function. A similar thing is happening with your example.

Comment: Are you sure there are "more" points in the output than the input?

Comment: Of course there are more points in the output image as it is bigger than than the input image.

Comment: What precisely does it mean when you say that a set $A$ has *more points* than another set $B$? Another example to think about is the set $A$ of all even integers and the set $B$ of all integers. $B\setminus A$ is infinite, but there is a still a well-defined function mapping $A$ onto all of $B$, namely $x\mapsto x/2$.

Comment: If you haven't already, you should read about cardinality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality

Comment: @VishalSunani You have just shown that there is a bijection between one region and the other. Therefore they contain exactly the same number of points (cardinality). So it follows that your intuition that one region contains more points because it has a larger area must be wrong.

Comment: Quoting a letter sent decades ago by a friend, after he had circulated a preprint that contained an error: "As usual, the mistake is in a sentence that begins with "Clearly.""

Comment: Hmm, understood what I was misinterpreting. The output image depends on the input image. Thanks everyone for responding.

Comment: In terms of bijection both regions contain exactly the same number of points but graphically it's confusing to accept that a region with larger area contains same number of points as in a region with smaller area.@gandalf61

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is "loaded" with difficulties that might stem from working with complex numbers.

A much simpler example would be: The interval $[0,1]\subset{\mathbb R}$ is scaled by the factor $2$ to the interval $[0,2]\subset{\mathbb R}$. Maybe you feel  that the second interval contains more points than the first. Nevertheless: Exactly one point of $[0,1]$ goes to exactly one point of $[0,2]$, and conversely: Each point of $[0,2]$ comes from exactly one point in $[0,1]$.

It is sufficient to really absorb the second situation.

Comment: In terms of bijection both regions contain exactly the same number of points but graphically it's confusing to accept that a region with larger area contains same number of points as in a region with smaller area.